# View own active questions

Tags: support, questions

Where can I find an overview of all my questions for which I haven't yet accepted an answer?

I know that I have a couple but at the moment, on my "Questions" page the ones without an accepted answer are shown inbetween the ones for which I already have accepted an answer.

Comment: no way I know of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Overflow's site search has an option called `hasaccepted` which you can use. Read more about the search options available to you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

A simple search for `user:me hasaccepted:0` should list the questions you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! How can I suggest to the admins to add a tab for this on the "questions"-page of a user's profile? I mean the part where it says "votes | activity | newest | views". Would be great if another tab could be added! This could be quite helpful considering that people often "friendly remind" other users that they should accept more answers!

Comment: @Ben: You can either edit/rephrase this question, or post a follow-up question linking to this one and tag it [feature-request].