# Tab for 'Questions without Accepted Answer' on User-Profiles

Tags: feature-request, search, tabs

On a user's profile, on the *questions*-tab, could there be added another *sorting-tab* (in addition to "votes | activity | newest | views") that shows **all questions for which  the user has not yet accepted an answer**.

i.e. I am asking for a sorting-tab that does the same what can be achieved by searching for `user:me hasaccepted:0`. I believe the tab would help to make it easier to view these questions and maybe encourage people to look at it more often, and hence ultimately lead people to accept more answers.

(This is  a follow-up question to [View own active questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117079/view-own-active-questions))

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why we need to add another tab, when we already have a search shortcut that works well. The four tabs we have for sorting questions is enough for newcomers to sort the most requested information quickly.

When you're viewing a profile, the profile ID is automaticaly displayed in the search bar. Select the search field, hit the enter key and a full list of the users questions will be displayed. From here you can add *'Advanced Super Ninja Search Options'* to refine your search.

Comment: Coincidently, I searched ['closed:0 answers:0'](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3a0%20answers%3a0) to find this question.

Comment: People are lazy. Why type when you could click? I'm using my own questions-page quite often to look for new answers to my questions. Having the new tab right there would be a lot more comfortable than having to locate the search-bar and typing in that string lengthy string (that many users are just gonna forget and will have to try to remember each time again). Should a user really be expected to know and remember all *''Advanced Super Ninja Search Options'*?

Comment: @Ben: I don't know *all* of the options and I use them, the search options are easy to remember and can be found [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search).