# How to see my questions for which I have not accepted an answer?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View own active questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117079/view-own-active-questions)

I'd like to review my questions for which I have not approved an answer.  It seems the obvious place to do that would be on my profile page, but I don't see an obvious way to do that.  Any other way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aquestion+hasaccepted%3A0):

```
user:me is:question hasaccepted:0
```

For more information about these operators, see [the search options page](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the page listing your questions, the ones where the number of answer is yellow are questions with an accepted answer.

[image: screenshot]

The green background just means one of the answers given for the question have been up-voted.

[image: screenshot]

As alternative, you can search for [user:me is:question hasaccepted:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aquestion+hasaccepted%3A1&submit=search). This is useful if you asked many questions, and just few of them don't have an accepted answer.

Comment: +1 That last little tid bit of information is really interesting. I did not know you could do that.